# I'm getting a NoSuchMethodError when setting a font on a TextView programically with the new font feature

Tags: android

From this official example https://developer.android.com/preview/features/working-with-fonts.html I'm trying to set a custom font for a `TextView` which works when set in XML/layout but not when setting it programmatically I get the following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method
>   getFont(I)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; in class
>   Landroid/content/res/Resources; or its super classes (declaration of
>   'android.content.res.Resources' appears in
>   /system/framework/framework.jar)

**This is how I'm doing it by code:**

```
    Typeface typeface = getResources().getFont(R.font.morganbold);
    providerTxv.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Is this a bug or I'm I doing something wrong?

I'm using `Android Studio Canary 9` with Gradle version: `gradle:3.0.0-alpha9`
with these support depedencies:

```
'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
```

Comment: Becuase `android.content.res.Resources` has no such method on lower android's versions ... you should use it in "compat" way

Comment: @Selvin I'm using Android 7.1.1 isn't that enough?

Comment: What is API level of 7.1.1 ? In which API level `Resources.getFont` was added? ... IIRC in support library there should static class which extends `Resources` class functionality

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must use

```
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.myfont);
```

[See docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html)

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution (**getFont()** will work from **Android 'O'(26.0.0-beta1)** version. So we have to move the below solution):

1. Put font.ttf/otf in assets folder

   ```
   Typeface light = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.ttf");
   ```
2. Set TypeFace in your view

   ```
    YourView.setTypeFace(light);
   ```

Please refer the link 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat.html#getFont(android.content.Context,int)